# How to implement csv or excel file upload in spring boot and jsp using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, jsp

I am new to Spring Boot, and I am trying to implement a csv or excel file upload in my application. I have created a button in JSP page to upload file and store in my database. To upload file from backend, I have created API and after testing API, it is working fine. But the code written inside the script is not working properly. I have written the below code:
Each time when I am trying to upload my file, I am getting 404 error. I do not know why. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
    function uploadpindata(){
            var delivercityid = document.getElementById('cityid').value;
            var formData = new FormData();
            var fileSelect = document.getElementById("file");
            if(fileSelect.files && fileSelect.files.length == 1) {
                var file = fileSelect.files[0];
                formData.set("file",file,file.name);
                console.log("Got the file");
            }else{
                $("#file").focus();
                return false;
            }
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            try {
                request.onreadystatechange=function() {
                    if(request.readyState==4) {
                        var v = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                        if(v.status==="OK") {
                            alert("New File Uploaded successfully");
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    }
                }
              request.open('POST',"../<%=AkApiUrl.uploadpincodedata%>/"+delivercityid);
              request.send(formData);
              } catch(e) {
                  swal("Unable to connect to server","","error");
              }
```

Comment: `const url = "../<%=AkApiUrl.uploadpincodedata%>/"+delivercityid;` then `console.log(url);` do you see what you expect to see? Also, XHRs can be inspected in the browser's dev tools; did you check the URL there?

Comment: Yes, URL is showing like: http://citistand.com/api/uploadpincodedata/27. But on hitting this url, I am getting Whitelabel error page.

Comment: I got URL like this:   ../api/uploadpincodedata/27

Comment: Well, your backend is supposed to be set up to reply to the API request, so you need to show relevant Springboot code I guess.

Comment: Is the code written in frontend is correct?

Comment: It looks mostly ok, yes (`XMLHttpRequest` is obsolete; using `fetch()` instead is much simpler).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230877/discussion-between-rakhi-sharma-and-chris-g).